# Find rails model instances where `belongs_to` model instances were created in the last 24 hours

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure if I am wording this correctly or not.

I have two models `store_attachments` and `store`.

The `store_attachments belongs_to store`, but `store has_many attachments`.

The `store_attachments` have a `created_at` field.

I have a scope to find the `store_attachments` that were created in the last 24 hours, but I cannot seem to call it on the `store` model.

I currently have `Store.store_attachments.added_within 24.hours.ago`.

I see really why that one doesn't work, but I'm not really sure how I would figure that out. `Store_attachments` must belong to a `Store`, so it's not used anywhere else.

My code for the scope...

`scope :added_within, lambda { |time_ago| { :conditions => ['created_at < ?', time_ago] } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you're passing in the date from 24 hours ago, you'd want the following conditional:

`scope :added_within, lambda { |time_ago| { :conditions => ['created_at > ?', time_ago] } }`

You had a `<`, which would mean older than the time you passed into the scope.

Also, you would need an instance of the Store class before using the relation, so you'd need

```
store = Store.first
store.store_attachments.added_within 24.hours.ago
```

I've always used a regular old class method instead of scopes. It just seems more readable to me.

```
class StoreAttachments < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.added_within(time_ago = 24.hours.ago)
    where("created_at > ?", time_ago)
  end

  # vs

  scope :added_within, lambda { |time_ago| { conditions: [ 'created_at > ?', time_ago] } }
end
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping I didn't have to do a `@stores = Store.all` `@stores.each do |store|` I didn't want to have to append it to variable array. I knew that was my other option.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to filter to a single Store instance, you would just use the scope right on the StoreAttachments like so `StoreAttachments.added_within(24.hours.ago)`. That would return all attachments created within the past 24 hours, regardless of which store they belong to.